# How to convert SCORM 1.2 or SCORM 2004 3rd Edition package to SCORM 2004 4th Edition?

Tags: scorm

I have the SCORM 1.2 and SCORM 2004(3rd edition) packages. But, I am looking forward to convert or create a package in SCORM 2004 - 4th edition.

***Note:*** I have the packages in HTML version, not in Flash.

Is there any tool to create or convert the package into SCORM 2004 4th edition?

Please help me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

About SCORM 1.2 to SCORM 2004 - Your looking at namespace changes that will not be a 1:1 conversion.  There are libraries that can aid in allowing you to migrate old to new namespaces, but also keep in mind character limits, vocab/states also changed.

I had put together a sample of these differences in a PDF - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3459294/SCOBot-Content-API-Standards-Breakdown.pdf
There is also more information on https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot/wiki about some of the scenarios.

SCORM 2004 4th Ed was mainly a Sequence and Navigation update.  Some of what changed between SCORM 2004 2nd, 3rd and 4th editions were mainly surrounding the imsmanifest.xml and the packaging of the content.  Like describing objectives, flow rules and such.

I would say a large portion of content produced follows the SCORM 1.2 model where it simply performs a "I was here".  You might get status, score, and time but a large portion of SCORM 1.2 was optional so you rarely get interactions and objectives.
SCORM 2004 solidified more of it as mandatory so you can take more advantage of these features but if the content is coming from SCORM 1.2 you'd have to add that new capability (most likely).

Answer (score 0):

The various 2004 editions basically just add extra stuff to the manifest - so as you're "upconverting" nothing needs to be done for those ones.

The 1.2 packages will have more changes - both in the manifest and the API addressing code - the API side can probably get changed as simple search & replace (the API name changed, as did the "cmi.*" keys) - the manifest I'm not so sure on the exact changes simply because I've run both from scratch and not had to convert before.